# Standard sizes for Windows app splash screens

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

I created a app in WPF and as app launches it has splash screen. But I was not sure what is the standard size for splash screens or what is the size Office 2010 is using for their splash screens.

Comment: What are you trying to cover up?  A user with stone-age hardware won't be surprised when it doesn't fit.  She's seen it before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Office 2010 suite splash screen is approximately 500 x 335 for its splash screen.

I'm not sure if there are any "standard" sizes for splash screens, but you could try looking at the Patterns & Practices documents or UX Guidelines documents that Microsoft publishes and see if they are mentioned there.

Interestingly enough, the [Windows 7/Vista UX Interaction Guidelines](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=e49820cb-954d-45ae-9cb3-1b9e8ea7fe8c) contains the following section:

> Reconsider animated splash screens (as
>   well as static splash screens). Often
>   splash screens just draw attention to
>   how long a program takes to load, and
>   they wear out their welcome quickly.
>   While splash screens are acceptable if
>   they are displayed only when user
>   interaction isn't possible, whenever
>   practical a better alternative is to
>   design your program so that users can
>   interact with it immediately, even
>   while it is still loading.

Comment: What resolution is your screen set to?

Comment: I'm running 1280x1024. I took a screenshot while Word was opening up and cropped out just to the splash screen.

Comment: my screen resolution is 1280X1024. but user of the app can go to any resolution.

Comment: Precisely, and that's why David's suggestion is spot on to not make it too large. It is often better to assume a smaller resolution for your average user (say 1024 x 768) and allow the app to gracefully expand in area for those on larger resolutions.

Answer (score 2):

There is no standard. I would avoid making it too big and I'd definitely let the user switch it off if they wanted too - they often perceive that it slows down the startup.

Comment: well the reason is to add the splash screen is only to give feedback and reduce the perception of time for programs that have unusually long load times.